# N queen with an array and recursion

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve n queen problem with an 1D array and recursion. 
As you can see in the code array's indices are the column numbers and array's values are the row numbers of queens' positions.
I think I gave the right condition to if statement of the function check_safe, but it fails to position queens exclusively.

eg) Input N: 12

1 3 0 2 4 8 10 0 0 5 7 0

Can anyone help me find where in the code is causing the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

void put_queen (int column, int* array, int array_size);
bool check_safe (int column, int row, int* array);

int main (void){
    int* array;
    int array_size, column;
    printf("Input N: ");
    scanf("%d", &array_size);

    array = (int*) calloc( array_size, sizeof(int) );

    srand(time(NULL));
    array[0]= rand() % array_size; 

    column = 1;
    put_queen(column, array, array_size);

    //print the result
    for( column = 0; column < array_size; column++){
        printf("%3d", array[column]);
    }

    free(array);
    return 0;
}

bool check_safe (int column, int row, int* array){
    for(int index = 0 ; index < column; index++ ){  
        if( (row == array[index]) || (abs(row - array[index]) == abs(index-column) )){
            return false;           
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void put_queen (int column, int* array, int array_size){
    for( int row = 0; row < array_size; row++){
        if(check_safe(column, row, array)){
            array[column] = row;
            break;          
            }
        }
    if( column == array_size - 1){return ;} 
    put_queen( column + 1, array, array_size);
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the result you give, my output is '0 2 4 1 3 8 10 0 0 5 7 0'; furthermore, why do you initialize the board's first entry with a random value?

Comment: @Codor If I don't initialize the first element of the array, it will be always 0 because in put_queen function I made for loop to start by row 0 and since first column has no predecessor function check_safe will return true, then array[0]=0 would be executed.

Comment: What was the intention behind using recursion here? In your code the recursion is equivalent to just calling put_queen() in a loop with column going from 0 to array_size - 1 (inclusive). You do not seem to have any kind of heuristic nor backtracking implemented - placing queen to the first spot available is not going to yield a good solution unless N is very low.

Comment: That was also my thought, but I wasn't sure.